# gpg encrypt only certain files in a folder

Tags: bash, gnupg

There are 15 files in a folder, all with gz extension. I want to encrypt only 12 out of them and skip the 3 files. Is there any way to do this? all files names are different and may or maynot start with the same letter.
currently am doing :

```
gpg -r 'name' --encrypt-files  $source/*.gz
```

Say the file names are apple.gz, alabama.gz, butter.gz, cake.gz, dog.gz, eagle.gz, oregon.gz, somename.gz;

I want to encrypt all files except alabama.gz and somename.gz with one gpg command ;
How can I do this?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want to do.  Perhaps show the 15 file names you have and identify which 2 you want to exclude.

Comment: @Bob Duell : Added file name examples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you already know (from what you posted), Bob's answer is wrong to say that you can't encrypt multiple files with a single command.

You're almost there with your own command-line; you just need a little shell trickery, e.g.:

```
gpg -r recip --encrypt-files $(ls $source/*.gz | egrep -v 'alabama|somename')
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you CAN encrypt multiple files with a single command if you want to encrypt ALL the files in the folder.

```
gpg -r 'name' --encrypt-files *.gz
```

Works just fine. Ryan's answer is correct if you want to skip those 2 files though.

Scott

Answer (score -2):

You cannot encrypt multiple files with a single `gpg` command.  However, you could `tar` them all into an archive and then encrypt the result.  See [this similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43846/20450) on the UNIX site for more info.

In any case, you will need to list the files you want to include.